# RxJava Observable to Completable, how to avoid toBlocking()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, kotlin

I am currently using RxJava on Android with Kotlin, but I have a problem and I can't solve without using toBlocking().

I have method in employee service which returns an Observable>:

```
fun all(): Observable<List<Employee>>
```

This is all and good since this Observable emits the new list of employees whenever an employee changes. But I'd like to generate a PDF file from the employees, which obviously doesn't need to run everytime an employee changes. Also, I'd like to return a `Completable` object from my PDF generator method. I want to add a header to my PDF, and then iterate through the employees and calculate the wage of each employee, which also returns an Observable, and this is the place where I am using toBlocking right now. My current approach is this:

```
private fun generatePdf(outputStream: OutputStream): Completable {
    return employeeService.all().map { employees ->
        try {
                addHeaderToPDF()
                for (i in employees) {
                    val calculated = employeeService.calculateWage(i.id).toBlocking().first()
                    // Print calculated to PDF....
                }
                addFooterToPDF()
                return @map Completable.complete()
            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
                return @map Completable.error(e)
            }
        }.first().toCompletable()
```

Is there any way to make this code a little cleaner using RxJava?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No for loops, no forEach. Basically everything has to be observable, including `addHeaderToPDF` and `addFooterToPDF`. `calculateWage` should return a `Single`, it either returns one value or errors.

Comment: `calculateWage` is an `Observable` because it emits the recalculated values of an employee upon a change. Can you please show me an example how to do this right? I cannot put the puzzle together. :(

Comment: ~Good, but how's a changing value going to help you print an immutable PDF? You need one value of wage at the time of printing of each emloyee.~ Understood, it's an observable to begin with. I'm working on something concise, stay tuned...

Comment: Read this http://konmik.com/post/when_to_not_use_rxjava/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* This answer is a work in progress.

---

*Basic premise:* If you have `blocking` in the stream, you're doing it wrong.

*Note:* No state must leave the observable lambda.

## Step 1: Stream the whole data set

The input is a stream of employees. For each employee you need to get one wage. Let's make it into one stream.

```
/**
 * @param employeesObservable
 * Stream of employees we're interested in.
 * @param wageProvider
 * Transformation function which takes an employee and returns a [Single] of their wage.
 * @return
 * Observable stream spitting individual [Pair]s of employees and their wages.
 */
fun getEmployeesAndWagesObservable(
        employeesObservable: Observable<Employee>,
        wageProvider: Function<Employee, Single<Int>>
): Observable<Pair<Employee, Int>>? {
    val employeesAndWagesObservable: Observable<Pair<Employee, Int>>

    // Each Employee from the original stream will be converted
    // to a Single<Pair<Employee, Int>> via flatMapSingle operator.
    // Remember, we need a stream and Single is a stream.
    employeesAndWagesObservable = employeesObservable.flatMapSingle { employee ->
        // We need to get a source of wage value for current employee.
        // That source emits a single Int or errors.
        val wageForEmployeeSingle: Single<Int> = wageProvider.apply(employee)

        // Once the wage from said source is loaded...
        val employeeAndWageSingle: Single<Pair<Employee, Int> = wageForEmployeeSingle.map { wage ->
            // ... construct a Pair<Employee, Int>
            employee to wage
        }

        // This code is not executed now. It will be executed for each Employee
        // after the original Observable<Employee> starts spitting out items.
        // After subscribing to the resulting observable.
        return@flatMapSingle employeeAndWageSingle
    }

    return employeesAndWagesObservable
}
```

What's going to happen when you subscribe:

1. Take an employee from source.
2. Fetch wage of an employee.
3. Spit out a pair of employee and their wage.

This repeats  until `employeesObservable` signals `onComplete` or something fails with `onError`.

Used operators:

- [flatMapSingle](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html): Converts an actual value into a new Single stream of some transformed value.
- [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html): Converts an actual value into some other actual value (no nested streams).

Hee's how you'd hook it up to your code:

```
fun doStuff() {
    val employeesObservable = employeeService.all()
    val wageProvider = Function<Employee, Single<Int>> { employee ->
        // Don't listen to changes. Take first wage and use that.
        employeeService.calculateWage(employee.id).firstOrError()
    }

    val employeesAndWagesObservable = 
            getEmployeesAndWagesObservable(employeesObservable, wageProvider)

    // Subscribe...
}
```

Used operators:

- [first](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html): Take the first item from observable and turn it into a Single stream.
- [timeout](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html): A good idea would be to `.timeout` the wage if you're getting it over network.

## Next steps

### Option 1: End here

Don't subscribe, call

```
val blockingIterable = employeesAndWagesObservable.blockingIterable()
blockingIterable.forEach { ... }
```

and process each item in a synchronous fashion. Sit back, figure out next steps, watch presentations, read examples.

### Option 2: Add layers

1. `.map` each of these `Pair<Employee, Int>` to some abstract PDF building block.
2. Turn your header and footer printers to Observables via `Observable.fromCallable { ... }`, have them return PDF building blocks too.
3. Merge all of these in a sequential manner via `Observable.concat(headerObs, employeeDataObs, footerObs)`
4. `.subscribe` to this result and start writing the PDF building blocks to a PDF writer.
5. TODO:

   - Figure out a way to initialize the PDF writer lazily on subscription (not before building the stream),
   - Delete output on error,
   - Close output stream on complete or on error.

Comment: Nice, but what do you gain by using observables in this scenario?

Comment: @KarsenGauss The input is one observable + one more observable for each employee. I went the rx way for as long as my mind allowed me after a week of rx. That was the goal: *No mixing of blocking and non-blocking code, stream for as long as possible.* And as mentioned another step would be to convert more blocking code to rx.

Comment: Your answer is great, don't get me wrong. I am just trying to highlight that sometimes it may be worth to take a step back and consider a non-reactive approach. I don't see that many benefits of a reactive solution for @szantogab's problem.

Comment: @KarsenGauss You and me both :D However there is a way to stream to PDF file at the end of this (for syantogab). And to get better at rx along the way (for me).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
    return employeeService.all().first()
            .doOnSubscribe { addHeaderToPDF() }
            .flatMapIterable { it }
            .flatMap { employeeService.calculateWage(it.id).first() }
            .doOnNext { printEmployeeWage(it) }
            .doOnCompleted { addFooterToPDF }
            .toCompletable()
```

Is this how it is supposed to be done? :)

Comment: In the meantime I figured out that it will not work, because in the `doOnNext` and `doOnCompleted` closure I need to reach the PDF file that is created in the `doOnSubscribe` closure. How to do that? :S